# Gwt super dev mode: recompile doesn't work

Tags: gwt, gwt-super-dev-mode

Super Dev Mode starts successfully, but after I make changes to the code and try to recompile it from the browser, GWT reports the following error:

```
GET /recompile/de.marketmaker.iview.mmgwt.mmweb.Mmweb
   Job de.marketmaker.iview.mmgwt.mmweb.DevMmweb_1_4
      starting job: de.marketmaker.iview.mmgwt.mmweb.DevMmweb_1_4
      binding: locale=default
      binding: user.agent=gecko1_8
      Compiling module de.marketmaker.iview.mmgwt.mmweb.DevMmweb
         [ERROR] Current binding properties are expanding to more than one permutation but per-file compilation requires that each compile operate on only one permutation.
      [WARN] recompile failed
      [WARN] continuing to serve previous version
```

Any idea why this happens? I found the following thread, but it gives no solution: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit-contributors/5lgtM77-1tM

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem as I switch from GWT 2.6.1 to 2.7.0.

Using GWT 2.6.0 I reload the application by pressing the "Dev Mode On" bookmark. Pressing the bookmark using GWT 2.7.0 causes this error.

For me, the issue was solved by using browser refresh (F5 or cmd+r).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! Switching Dev mode Off and then On also helps. But it looks like workaround.

Comment: In GWT 2.7.0 there is no need to use the bookmarks anymore.

Comment: Didn't know that, but how will the page understand that it should connect to super dev mode process?

Answer (score 1):

Long discussion here I'm involved in:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/google-web-toolkit-contributors/5lgtM77-1tM/rnNdb5UbDB8J

Basically, in old style direct running of Super Dev Mode (SDM) adding a -noincremental option works for us.

We've also tried the new 2.7 style approach of launching Dev Mode which defaults now to SDM. Our app serves resources from packaged bundles though, so it looks like the new model can't intercept the application by changing the .nocache.js file